# auto submit on CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I have CGridView on my site. A wont add autocomplete filter. But when i select item from autocomplete drop-down list my grid submit data and after then set selected value.

How disable auto submit on CGridView (YII). Maybe we have access  to onChange method.

Comment: Maybe a piece of code would be more helpful for others to find out the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found one bad solution. This code need to be inserted after widget.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('#script', "$('body').undelegate('change');");
```